# Delayed instantiation in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a variable without instantiating the object.

In Python it would look like this:

```
graph = mymap[c] if c in mymap else Graph()
```

So I basically check if I already have that graph otherwise I create it. My understanding is that if I declare the following in C++ it will call the constructor and *be wasteful*.

```
Graph g;
```

So I'm trying to use pointers to avoid this "waste":

```
    Graph* g;

    if (graphs.find(c) == graphs.end()){
        g = new Graph();
        graphs[c] = *g;
    } else {
        g = &(graphs[c]);
    }

    std::cout << g << std::endl;
    std::cout << &(graphs[c]) << std::endl;
```

The problem is that the addresses printed in the end do not match. In fact, my tests show that something weird is happening like a new instance of Graph is being created every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maps already do this. You are allocating an object, then dereferencing it and copying it inside your map, leaking the allocation. Basically not doing what you think it does.

Comment: Could you complete the example, showing the type of `c` and of `graphs` (the latter presumably an `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: There are better solutions, as detailed in 1+ answers, but to clarify: `graphs[c] = *g` is not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't have to do anything fancy here. You can simply do

```
Graph* g = &graphs[c];
```

The reason is that [`map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) has the following behavior:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

So if the key has an associated value already, you'll get a reference to that object. If that key does not yet exist, a value will be default constructed and inserted for you, and a reference to that new object will be returned.

Comment: Even better, it could just be Graph& g = graphs[c], where graphs calls `Graph`'s default constructor, and no memory management is needed.

Comment: That is exactly what my answer is stating, the only difference is whether you return a reference or a pointer, the allocation and construction is identical to what you demonstrated in your comment

Comment: Yeah, I get that, I was just making a comment to point out the extra niceties your suggestion provides, since the code in the OP's question is leaky...

Comment: Can I just do `Graph g = graphs[c];`? Would that be equivalent to the Python code? I started messing with pointers because I thought it was the only way.

Comment: `Graph g = graphs[c];` would copy. Probably not what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer already says the right way to do what you're asking, but I'll address (ha!) why the addresses don't match:

On this line:

```
    graphs[c] = *g;
```

You're creating a *COPY* of the graph you just made with `new` that `g` points to, and that copy has a different address.  You're then printing the address of the original and the address of the copy, so obviously they're at different addresses.

```
graphs[c] = ...
```

This code already does the allocation and construction of a (default) Graph object to be stored inside the map when there isn't one mapped to `c` already (which you already checked for).. the assignment after that just makes the Graph object it just created look like the one that you had previously created with the call to `new`.